# How to make a plot with multiple bars using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a pandas data frame and am trying to make a multi-bar bar chart using seaborn. I want to have each set of trials for the `RF_#` labels grouped together; for example, I want `RF_1` to be separate from `RF_6` and want the five trials for each respective `RF_#` value to be next to each other but separate from the other `RF_#` groups.

I have read that to make this kind of bar chart, the melt function needs to be used first, but I'm not sure how that would work for my specific data frame.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `melt` the dataframe, then use `seaborn`'s `x` and `hue` arguments to create the groupings you're looking for. The example below could benefit from some column renaming and visual tweaking, but this should get you in the right direction.

Note that you can perform the `melt` directly in the `seaborn.barplot` command, but you may want to reassign this melted dataframe to a new variable for use in other plotting commands.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'RF_1': {'Trial_1': 64.66,
  'Trial_2': 48.37,
  'Trial_3': 84.0,
  'Trial_4': 11.16,
  'Trial_5': 77.05},
 'RF_6': {'Trial_1': 37.19,
  'Trial_2': 17.14,
  'Trial_3': 1.5,
  'Trial_4': 66.14,
  'Trial_5': 24.19},
 'RF_7': {'Trial_1': 6.81,
  'Trial_2': 31.22,
  'Trial_3': 80.24,
  'Trial_4': 4.04,
  'Trial_5': 58.26},
 'RF_8': {'Trial_1': 20.97,
  'Trial_2': 44.52,
  'Trial_3': 11.38,
  'Trial_4': 75.17,
  'Trial_5': 92.25},
 'RF_9': {'Trial_1': 95.29,
  'Trial_2': 19.66,
  'Trial_3': 98.07,
  'Trial_4': 54.02,
  'Trial_5': 86.31}})

sns.barplot(x='RF', y='value', hue='index',
            data=df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index', var_name='RF'))
```

[image]